# Reuse hidden buttons in a custom tableViewCell cell [ios]

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

I want to reuse table view cell buttons. Initially I have two buttons in the cell as hidden and one button visible. when I click on the visible button the hidden two buttons will also be visible. I set the button target action. here is my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellForEndItem", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CellForEndItem
        cell.incrementBtn.isHidden = true
        cell.decrementBtn.isHidden = true
        cell.priceLbl.text = "$ 200"
        
        cell.counterBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.incrementBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.decrementBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.counterBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CounterBtnTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside) }
```

Now bellow is my CounterBtnTapped method..

```
var count: Int = 0
    func CounterBtnTapped(sender: UIButton) {
            self.count += 1
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)    
            let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellForEndItem",for: indexPath) as! CellForEndItem
            cell.incrementBtn.isHidden = false
            cell.decrementBtn.isHidden = false
            sender.setTitle(String(self.count), for: .normal)
    }
```

But somehow, the increment and decrement buttons are not visible. What the wrong I am doing here. Need experts suggestion??

Answer (score 1):

Simply put a button to navigation item through storyboard and change it's background color. create a outlet of `UIButton` and make rounded corner.

[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var barBtn: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()


   barBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 5
   barBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1
   barBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
 }
```

Comment: the question is improved.. somewhat changed... That's the reason

Comment: Okay no problem. but if you have new problem raise separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom button and then add customView to the navigationbar button that is rightbarbuttonitem in your case.

```
var view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
var barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```

Add the relevant code to make your button look like design and then add it in the customView.

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom view as barButtonItem.

```
let customButton = UIButton(frame: .zero)
// configure title text and color, background color, action, etc. using UIButton functions.
// configure shadow, cornerRadius using customButton.layer properties
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was for   refreshing tableView Cell. I added the following line of code

`tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)`

It works as well.